# Payment system for PHP / MySQL based website

Tags: php, sql, system, payment

I created a website for a retail brand.

My website is coded on PHP, HTML, CSS and some JS. Now, I need to put in place a payments system. I have a shopping cart code implemented already and would like to permit the user to pay online.

I would obviously like to minimize costs. I know Paypal charges the seller a big % of the amount paid. Would there be any other cheaper/free and of course secure option someone could recommend for online payment that I could attach to my site?

Comment: paypal are actually one of the cheaper gateways as there is no monthly fixed rate, which all the banks and bank operated gateways do have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) in the past. It's secure and has an incredibly easy API to implement.

Answer (score 0):

eBay charges almost 4%, stripe charges 2.9% + $0.30